# Python look ahead regex

Tags: python, regex

```
s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．anycontent'
ExpectResult = [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']
```

I have a unicode str like that. I need to separate those options to four different substrings which start with A．, B．, C．,D．(．is not dot, it's a special character). How can I achieve the expected result? Thanks everyone!! The ABCD options are from the multiple choices questions. At most four options no EFGH...etc but could be just one or two options like only A．or A．, B．together

Comment: Don't call your string variables `str`. That's the name of the built-in data type, you don't want to override that.

Comment: Note that the `'．'` in your string is a single code point. Not two characters as you suppose. Your pattern has to reflect this. Besides you're splitting on character before the lookahead, so it won't be included in the split.

Comment: Guys my bad. I didn't clarify well. The four option's content can be anything not like numbers. It can be anything any language. It's the options of the multiple choices

Comment: Also the content might have ABCD letter as well. So what I wanted is to separate the four options starting with A．etc with the content followed by

Answer (score 0):

You have done some mistakes.

You should decide - will you use regex groups for reading or splits. You are lost.

It the first variant - look for your special dot. You should use your special dot, and after that - the normal dot, followed by + - that would mean that string you are looking for.

```
A.(.+)B.(.+)C.(.+)D.(.+)  // read groups by that regex
```

If you need these A. and things to be found, too, use:

```
(A..+)(B..+)(C..+)(D..+) 
or
u'(A..+)',u'(B..+)',u'(C..+)',u'(D..+)'
```

, if you need these `u'...',` constructions.

If the second case (splits) is what you need - your lookaheads in splits are senseless. The regex for the splitting substring should be much more simple:

```
'[A-D]．'   // use your special dot here
```

That is all. Really, I don't like the second variant, for you cannot be sure that you are not reading the line as `aaaB.bbbC.ccc` as a correct one. And you are having aaa substring without having `A.` . Whereas in the first variant you know that the first group is from A., the second - from B. and so on.

Comment: Hi Gangnus. Sorry for the late reply. Yeah I meant to use findall not split. That's my mistake. A.(.+)B.(.+)C.(.+)D.(.+) pattern seems to work fine but I ended up get without the A. B. C. D. in each substrings. How can I remain those in the beginning of each substring

Comment: If can't be, I can just add the ABCD to each substrings as well. But I think there is a way to make the pattern to including those. Your pattern is close enough

Comment: The general string is like: s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．a‌​nycontent'. The expect result should be [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']. The any content is just a general phrase. It can be anything in real cases. Also it's the ABCD options for the multiple choices question. Just these four no EFG...etc

Comment: Also your pattern result is [(u'anycontentfollowedby', u'anycontentanylength', u'anycontent', u'anycontent')] Is that a generator inside a list? Could it be [u'anycontentfollowedby', u'anycontentanylength', u'anycontent', u'anycontent']? The best would be [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod look the added (second) example. Only don't forget - these dots are different - the first one in each pair is your special dot, the second - a normal dot

Comment: Your patter works. Maybe I ask why the result is like this:
 [(u'A\uff0eanycontentfollowedby', u'B\uff0eanycontentanylength', u'C\uff0eanycontent', u'D\uff0eanycontent')] There is a tuple inside a list. Can it be [u'A\uff0eanycontentfollowedby', u'B\uff0eanycontentanylength', u'C\uff0eanycontent', u'D\uff0eanycontent'] this format?

Comment: Also I just found out there is another case that's just have A option or A and B option no CD. Can these case be covered as well? Cuz your pattern now only works for all four ABCD options

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod You have published a question. I have answered. If you want other answers on other questions, mark this one answer and make other questions. What you are doing now - asking more and more, is considered a very bad practice here. Don't change the question, too, please. Also think about upvoting interesting answers not simply repeating the others.

Comment: I can't upvote answers. Sorry I am new here so don't know how this exactly work. Thanks for you time

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod You already can mark an answer as the needed one.  Click the large check under the number (0) before the answer for that - and get 2 points of reputation for it. As for upvoting, wait for better reputation (You have already got +5 from me, with one or two useful answers or interesting questions it won't take long) and after that return to your first question(s) and upvote answers that you liked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need look ahead here. "+" - must be escaped as it is special symbol:

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Z]．\+\d', str)
['A．+4', 'B．+5', 'C．+6', 'D．+7']
```

And don't name your variable as "str"

**Update #1:**
It's better to clarify everything at start. So, this is new answer, more complicated (I leave first just for understanding and history):

```
>>> s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．anycontent'    
>>> re.findall('.+?(?=[A-D]．|$)',s)
['A．anycontentfollowedby', 'B．anycontentanylength', 'C．anycontent', 'D．anycontent']
```

Brief explanation:

- (?=[A-D]．|$)  - look ahead for 'A．' 'B．', etc. or end of line ($)
- .+? -  any symbols before that look ahead match, but not greedy (?). It means that it will find before first match, not till the last match.

Comment: Hey Sergius. I didn't clarify my case clearly. Please check my other response. Basically the general string is like: s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．a‌​nycontent'. The expect result should be [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']. The any content is just a general phrase. It can be anything in real cases. Also it's the ABCD options for the multiple choices question. Just these four no EFG...etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = u'A．+4B．+5C．+6D．+7'

data = [i for i in re.findall('.{4}', s)]
```

Output:

```
[u'A\uff0e+4', u'B\uff0e+5', u'C\uff0e+6', u'D\uff0e+7']
```

Comment: The four option's content can be anything not like numbers. It can be anything any language. It's the options of the multiple choices. Sorry I didn't clarify that part well

Comment: @this solution does not rely on numbers only. It will handle any characters in the form `[a-zA-Z0-9]．\+[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: But the length of the option content will be different as well. Could be longer could be shorter

Comment: And where are these special dots after A,B,C,D and these letters themselves in regex?

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that the `'．'` in your string is a single code point. Not two ascii characters as you suppose:

```
s = u'A．+4B．+5C．+6D．+7'
print repr(s)
# u'A\uff0e+4B\uff0e+5C\uff0e+6D\uff0e+7'
```

You should consider this while building your pattern:

```
pattern = ur'[^\d]+．\+\d'
print repr(pattern)
# u'[^\\d]+\uff0e\\+\\d'
```

Besides, you're splitting on the character before the look-ahead, so that character won't be included in the split except you use a grouping parens, which however puts that character separate in the result with `re.split`. You're better off with `re.findall`:

```
print re.findall(pattern, s)
# [u'A\uff0e+4', u'B\uff0e+5', u'C\uff0e+6', u'D\uff0e+7']
```

Comment: The four option's content can be anything not like numbers. It can be anything any language. It's the options of the multiple choices. Sorry I didn't clarify that part well

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod I've used a negated character class: `[^\d]` which should handle that properly.

Comment: what about this case: s = u'A．+4B．+5C．+6D．+7dadadada' ? the length of the content could be different as well. For D option it should be D．+7dadadada now

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod Looks confusing. Shouldn't it be `s = u'A．+4B．+5C．+6dadadada．+7'`? Show a [mcve] of what you're trying to match and try not to make up random cases.

Comment: s = u'A．+4optionAB．+5optionBC．+6optionCD．+7optionD' The expect result should be [u'A．+4optionA', u'B．+5optionB', u'C．+6optionC', u'D．+7optionD'] It always separated by [A-D][．] as a starting symbol then follow whatever it has until reach another [A-D][．] pattern

Comment: @Tmac_shamgod In that case, you can use: `pattern = ur'[^\d]．\+\d[^\d]+(?=[A-Z])'`

Comment: Yeah that pattern works for the one case I gave above. It doesn't work for the case I put in my question s = u'A．+4B．+5C．+6D．+7'. I'm trying to find a pattern that works for all kinds of content followed by ''A．xxxB．xxxC．xD．'. Like I said before, the only similar with this string is it has 'A．B．C．D．' it can be followed by whatever content is then separate each ABCD option into four different substring

Comment: The general string is like:  s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．anycontent'. The expect result should be [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']. The any content is just a general phrase. It can be anything in real cases. Also it's the ABCD options for the multiple choices question. Just these four no EFG...etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there will be better options than what I'm coding here but it will give you some hints to solve problem.

You have two options to get desired result. Assuming your test string

1) Using `re.findall`

```
result = re.findall(r"([a-d].*?\d)", data, re.IGNORECASE)
print(result)
```

2) By Splitting string

```
import re
data = r"A. +4B．+5C．+6D．+7"
result = [x for x in re.split(r"([a-d].*?\d)", data, 0, re.IGNORECASE) if x != '']
print(result)
```

Output is `['A. +4', 'B．+5', 'C．+6', 'D．+7']`

See live demo at [repl.it](https://repl.it/Kgq4/1)

Comment: Hi Saleem. Sorry I didn't clarify my case well. Please check my other comment. Basically the content can be anything not like +4 etc. That's just the simplest use case. The general string is like: s = u'A．anycontentfollowedbyB．anycontentanylengthC．anycontentD．a‌​‌​nycontent'. The expect result should be [u'A．anycontentfollowedby', u'B．anycontentanylength', u'C．anycontent', u'D．anycontent']. The any content is just a general phrase. It can be anything in real cases. Also it's the ABCD options for the multiple choices question. Just these four no EFG...etc

Comment: Why for reading the big A-D you read small a-d and ignore case? Where are special dots? Why had you decide that substrings after ABCD can be empty?